# Red lines on the screen when I open Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics, display, screen, amd-graphics

Similar to my problem:

[image: Similar to my problem]

Like this image but here we see side bar.
When I try to open my laptop after update there are full of red lines on my screen.

Even though I reinstall the Ubuntu the problem doesn't solved yet.

How can I solve it.